# Los objetos no se dibujan y el display aparece en negro

Tags: python, poo, objeto, pygame

Estoy usando Pygame pero no consigo que mis objetos se dibujen correctamente. No obtengo ningún error y la aplicación responde correctamente. Los objetos se muestran correctamente en la consola (con el `print`), solo que el display aparece negro.

Este es mi código:

```
def draw_enviroment(blobs):
    game_display.fill(WHITE)
    for blob_id in blobs:
        blob = blobs[blob_id]
        pygame.draw.circle(game_display, blob.color, [blob.x, blob.y],     blob.size)
        blob.move()
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    blue_blobs = dict(enumerate([Blob(BLUE, i) for i in     range(STARTING_BLUE_BLOBS)]))
    print(blue_blobs)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

    draw_enviroment(blue_blobs)
    clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hola guille, las dos últimas líneas del `main` no se ejecutan mientras no se salga del ciclo `while` infinito, es decir nunca (dado que salir del ciclo inplica salir de la app). Pon un `print` justo antes de la llamada a `draw_enviroment` y mira a ver que pasa.

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te comenté tal y como tienes la función `main` las dos últimas líneas de ella nunca llegan a ejecutarse.

Dentro de tu ciclo infinito tienes tu ciclo `for` para responder a los eventos. Del ciclo infinito solo se sale cuando se genera el evento `pygame.QUIT` lo que implica salir de la aplicación. Por lo que tanto la línea encargada de dibujar los objetos, como el delay entre frames nunca llegan a ejecutarse.

Ambas líneas deben estar dentro del mainloop (`while True`) justo después del ciclo para eventos y no fuera:

```
def main():
    blue_blobs = dict(enumerate([Blob(BLUE, i) for i in     range(STARTING_BLUE_BLOBS)]))
    print(blue_blobs)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        draw_enviroment(blue_blobs)
        clock.tick(60)
```